# jfreechart along with other data in a web page

Tags: java, html, servlets

I have created a chart and converted the chart into an image and displaying it using a servlet using this code :

```
OutputStream out = p_resp.getOutputStream();

        p_resp.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        chart = u.genarateLineChart("month);
        ChartUtilities.writeChartAsJPEG(out, chart, 625, 800);
```

with this the web page contains only the chart image. I want to include in the web page a header for the chart as well as some data .
I tried to call this using html tags as follows but with no luck . Is there any way of displaying the chart with data too using servlets? I have tried the "img" tag too. 
I do not want to create an image of the chart and store it in a temporary location .

update 1:

I am using the below given code in order to open the image in a webpage :

```
  HTMLHelper.writeHTMLHead(m_out);
                 m_out.println("<body bgcolor=\"#B4A383\"> "
                            + "  <center> "
                            + "  <img src=\"/dashboard/_imgs/sungard_martini.png\" alt=\"SunGard Martini\" border=\"0\" /> "
                            + "  <p><br><br></p>");
                    m_out.println(
                             "  <div align=center>"
                            + "  <img src=\"/servlet/servlet-name" border=\"0\" /> "
                            +"</div>"
                            + "  <p><br><br></p>");
```

Thanks,
   Bhavya

Comment: Could you clarify, how you are trying to access the image? Is it for instance provided by separate servlet?

Comment: @M.L. I am trying to access the image directly by providing the "/servlet/servlet_name/" in the img tag of html. I am actually fetching the image and trying to display it directly in the same instance , can this be done ?

Comment: The example code producing the image response should be ok itself. No need to store files into temporary location. However, I'm still not understand how you are actually using that code in your servlet. Could you provide the code of the entire servlet as an example? Also, what happen when you insert the image-url to brower's address bar? What is the response then?

Comment: @M.L. I am currently storing the files in a temporary location and am able to see the images, I will update the question with the code that I am trying to use with the servlet code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encode the image as base64, then embed it using the general form:

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" 
  src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />
```